# Webdriver Timeout Exception

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I try to understand where is the problem in code:

```
class WebTest(unittest.TestCase):

@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    binary = FirefoxBinary('/home/andrew/Downloads/firefox 45/firefox')
    cls.browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
    cls.wait = WebDriverWait(cls.browser, 10)
    cls.browser.maximize_window()
    cls.browser.get('http://www.test.com/')

def test_login_menu_elements(self):
    self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='menu_min']"))).click() 
    check_icons(self)
    self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='menu_min']"))).click() 
    check_fields(self)

def test_add_news(self):
    self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(.,'News')]"))).click()
    self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='/manager/news']"))).click()    

@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    cls.browser.quit()

if __name__=='__main__':
   unittest.main()
```

Every time I receive TimeoutException, and I really don't understand why, and where is the problem in the code

Comment: could you post the stack trace and a minimum example of the HTML that can be used to reproduce the exception?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

A `TimeoutException` can be received without having any logical or syntantic errors with your code.

`TimeoutException`s will be raised when the `wait.until` expected conditions aren't found.

Some things I have found to help:

- Isolate the xpath by using chrome/firefox dev tools and right clicking on the element, and show xpath
- Using the xpath from the step above, make sure that the condition chose is correct
- ime having front end experience, using css selectors is usually more intuative and more understandable than relative xpaths.
- check the selector you are using by opening up dev tools console and using `$x({{ XPATH_HERE }})` to make sure it is valid
- for dynamic HTML use python debugger and make sure that html is in the expected state between each expected condition

Comment: But the problem is if I don't use in my code, wait.until I can find the element. For example if I use in my code time.sleep(1) I can find the element, and I didn't have the TimeoutException. I think that I have some problem with WebDriverWait, and I can't understand what the problem.

Comment: I think I founded where is the problem. The problem is, the page that I testing work with AJAX. And in this link http://training-course-material.com/training/Test_Automation_with_Selenium_(Python_Track) I saw that explicit waits not work with AJAX.